# MySQL INSERT query: Unknown column 'undefined' in 'field list'

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, express

`id` and `cost` are integers and cannot be NULL.

I am getting this error:

'Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'undefined' in 'field list''

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO Paintings(`painting_id`,`painting_title`,`img`,`cost`) VALUES("+id+",'"+title+"','"+img+"',"+cost+")";
```

This is my html form

```
<form action="/post" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                         <label>Painting id </label>
                         <input type="text" name="painting_id" id="painting_id" >
                    
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                         <label>Painting Title</label>
                         <input type="text" name="painting_title" id="painting_title" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                         <label>Image </label>
                         <input type="src" name="img" id="img">
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                         <label>Cost </label>
                         <input type="text" name="cost" id="cost">
                    </div>
                    <br/>
               <input type="submit" value="create painting"/>
</form>
```

This is my server side code

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mysql = require('mysql');
var session = require("express-session");


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
var urlencodedParser= bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});
app.use(express.json());


//======SQL CONNECTION========

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'admin',
    password: 'admin',
    database: 'artdb'
});

connection.connect(function(err){
    if(err){
        throw(err);
    }
    console.log("Connected to database");
})


app.get('/admin/painting',function(req,res){
        
        connection.query(`select * from Paintings`,(err,result,fields)=>{
            
            if(err){
                return console.log(err);
            }
            res.render("painting",{page_title:"Customers - Node.js",userData: result});
        });
        
    });

app.get('/painting/add', function(req,res,next){
    res.render('add_painting');

})

app.post('/post', function (req,res,next){

    var id= req.body.painting_id;
    var title = req.body.painting_title;
    var img = req.body.img;
    var cost = req.body.cost;
    var sql = "INSERT INTO Paintings(`painting_id`,`painting_title`,`img`,`cost`) VALUES("+id+",'"+title+"','"+img+"',"+cost+")";
    connection.query(sql,function(err,result){
        if(err) throw(err);
        console.log("Data Inserted");
        res.redirect('/admin/painting');
    });
});

app.listen(1100, ()=> {
    console.log("Server is running");
})
```

Comment: `id` must be `undefined` then, as that's what the error states

Comment: Is painting_id auto increment column?

Comment: no , painting_id INT PRIMARY KEY

Comment: @JaromandaX I have defined id as : var id= req.body.painting_id;

Comment: in that case `req.body.painting_id` is undefined

Comment: @AlexandreVelo - OP is doing that - you're just not reading the code correctly

Comment: @JaromandaX Can I send you my code? I am not able to debug it

Comment: no ... try `console.log(req.body.painting_id)` - if that's undefined then you'll need to figure out why ... perhaps your front end isn't sending an id, perhaps your server code is parsing the body of the request ...

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah I did console and got undefined ! But I seriously am not able to figure out why my frontend isn't sending . Would be great if you could help! I have edited my question

Comment: `var urlencodedParser= bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});` you never use `urlencodedParser` - just declaring a variable isn't enough

Comment: @JaromandaX YES Its working . Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @samxx - I posted is as an answer before you said that, because it was clear that was the issue, and none of this waffle about the SQL string itself :p

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use urlencoded body parser in your express app

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```

just declaring

```
var urlencodedParser= bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});
```

doesn't actually apply it to your app